# What is the difference between ffill in python as a chained method and as a parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we are trying to reindex a dataframe by a list as follows:

```
dataframe.reindex(list)
```

where the exact dataframe and the list is not important.

Now if the list is larger than the original index, there will be some NaNs. My question is if I want to fill the NaNs by forward-fill what is the difference between the two ways below:

```
dataframe.reindex(list, method='ffill')

dataframe.reindex(list).ffill()
```

I tried a few times and found the results are different.

Say we have dataframe is:

```
Jan   1  
Apr   2  
Jul   3  
Oct   4
```

and list is:
list = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

So,

```
dataframe.reindex(list, method='ffill')
```

becomes:

```
Jan   1  
Feb   2  
Mar   3  
Apr   2  
May   3  
Jun   3  
Jul   3  
Aug   2  
Sep   4  
Oct   4  
Nov   3  
Dec   2
```

Whereas,

```
dataframe.reindex(list).ffill()
```

becomes:

```
Jan   1  
Feb   1  
Mar   1  
Apr   2  
May   2  
Jun   2  
Jul   3  
Aug   3  
Sep   3  
Oct   4  
Nov   4  
Dec   4
```

I could not figure out how those two ways differ? What will the first way produce and what will the second way produce?

I tried to look up in the documentation and other sources but could not find an explanation. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: `I tried a few times and found the results are different.` - Can you add some data where is difference ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have added some data @jezrael.

Comment: What is your pandas version? It seems `print (dataframe.reindex(L, method='ffill'))` is buggy in some lower pandas versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

In version pandas 0.24.1 is raised error:

```
print (dataframe)
     Col
Jan    1
Apr    2
Jul    3
Oct    4

print (dataframe.index.is_monotonic_increasing)
False

L = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

print (dataframe.reindex(L, method='ffill'))
```

> ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

And in docs - [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

> **method** : {None, 'backfill'/'bfill', 'pad'/'ffill', 'nearest'}
>   Method to use for filling holes in reindexed DataFrame. Please note: this is only applicable to DataFrames/Series with a monotonically increasing/decreasing index.
>
> None (default): don't fill gaps
>   pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid
>   backfill / bfill: use next valid observation to fill gap
>   nearest: use nearest valid observations to fill gap

Second working nice:

```
print (dataframe.reindex(L).ffill())
     Col
Jan  1.0
Feb  1.0
Mar  1.0
Apr  2.0
May  2.0
Jun  2.0
Jul  3.0
Aug  3.0
Sep  3.0
Oct  4.0
Nov  4.0
Dec  4.0
```

---

Notice - Dont use `list` like variable, because python reserved word (builtins).

Difference is if missing values are in column before `reindex`:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col':[0,2,np.nan,5,np.nan]}, index=[1,3,5,6,8])
print (dataframe)
   col
1  0.0
3  2.0
5  NaN
6  5.0
8  NaN

print (dataframe.index.is_monotonic_increasing)
True
```

If use parameter it forward fill only added rows, here 1,4,7 rows.

If chain `ffill` then are created missing values and all data of Series are forward filling:

```
L = range(10)
df = pd.concat([dataframe.reindex(L, method='ffill'),
                dataframe.reindex(L),
                dataframe.reindex(L).ffill()], 
                keys=('parameter','only_reindex','chained'), axis=1)
print (df)
  parameter only_reindex chained
        col          col     col
0       NaN          NaN     NaN
1       0.0          0.0     0.0
2       0.0          NaN     0.0
3       2.0          2.0     2.0
4       2.0          NaN     2.0
5       NaN          NaN     2.0
6       5.0          5.0     5.0
7       5.0          NaN     5.0
8       NaN          NaN     5.0
9       NaN          NaN     5.0
```

---

If no missing values result are same:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col':[0,2,8,5,9]}, index=[1,3,5,6,8])
print (dataframe)
   col
1    0
3    2
5    8
6    5
8    9

print (dataframe.index.is_monotonic_increasing)
True

L = range(10)
df = pd.concat([dataframe.reindex(L, method='ffill'),
                dataframe.reindex(L),
                dataframe.reindex(L).ffill()], 
                keys=('parameter','only_reindex','chained'), axis=1)
print (df)
  parameter only_reindex chained
        col          col     col
0       NaN          NaN     NaN
1       0.0          0.0     0.0
2       0.0          NaN     0.0
3       2.0          2.0     2.0
4       2.0          NaN     2.0
5       8.0          8.0     8.0
6       5.0          5.0     5.0
7       5.0          NaN     5.0
8       9.0          9.0     9.0
9       9.0          NaN     9.0
```